# Preguntas y respuestas Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tratando de realizar un pequeño trivial en JS, no soluciono encontrar el error del if o de los arrays. En este caso la respuesta correcta sería b, lo que implica que teclear otra cosa es falso. ¿Qué he de modificar en este caso?

```js
var preguntas= new Array();
    
var respuesta=new Array();

preguntas[0]=new Array();

preguntas[0][0]= prompt("¿Cuánto mide el Everest? \n a: 8.912 m \n b:8.848 m \n c:8.800 m");
preguntas[0][1]="8.912";
preguntas[0][2]="8.848";
preguntas[0][3]="8.800";

respuesta[2]="b";

if(respuesta[2]=="b") {
  alert("Acierto");
}else {
  alert("Fallo");
}
```

Comment: Estás asignando a respuesta[2] (debería ser respuesta[0], seguramente) una b. A continuación compruebas si respuesta[2] es b. Siempre será verdad

Answer (score 2):

El caso es que siempre indicas que la solución independientemente de lo que el usuario diga es b en la siguiente línea:

```
respuesta[2]="b";
```

Estas guardando en la variable `preguntas[0][0]` lo que te contesta el usuario, por que tienes que guardar ese resultado en el de la respuesta.

```js
var preguntas= new Array();
    
var respuesta=new Array();

preguntas[0]=new Array();

preguntas[0][0]= prompt("¿Cuánto mide el Everest? \n a: 8.912 m \n b:8.848 m \n c:8.800 m");
preguntas[0][1]="8.912";
preguntas[0][2]="8.848";
preguntas[0][3]="8.800";

respuesta[2]=preguntas[0][0];

if(respuesta[2]=="b") {
  alert("Acierto");
}else {
  alert("Fallo");
}
```

Y si lo que quieres es guardar la respuesta en la variable `respuesta` entonces cambia el if de la comparación a esto:

```js
var preguntas= new Array();
    
var respuesta=new Array();

preguntas[0]=new Array();

preguntas[0][0]= prompt("¿Cuánto mide el Everest? \n a: 8.912 m \n b:8.848 m \n c:8.800 m");
preguntas[0][1]="8.912";
preguntas[0][2]="8.848";
preguntas[0][3]="8.800";

respuesta[2]="b";

if(respuesta[2]==preguntas[0][0]) {
  alert("Acierto");
}else {
  alert("Fallo");
}
```